# Kendo UI Dynamic Splitter panes with Angular 5

Tags: kendo-ui, angular2-template, splitter

For the latest update on this please see  the last code segment below. Both the outer  gets processed as does the ng-template with the ng-container however the content-pane never makes it to the page.

I'm trying to implement a Kendo splitter pane with dynamically allocated number of panes in Angular 55. I have the  element in the parent component but unless I remove it the child component doesn't get rendered.

**Parent Splitter Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrxDelta } from '../model/BrxDelta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-deltas',
  template: `<kendo-splitter orientation="vertical" style="height: 340px;">

              <app-brx-delta *ngFor="let b of brxDeltas" [brxDelta]="b"></app-brx-delta>

            </kendo-splitter>`,
  styleUrls: ['all-deltas.component.scss']
})
export class AllDeltasComponent implements OnInit {

  brxDeltas: BrxDelta[];

  constructor() {
    this.brxDeltas = [
      new BrxDelta("DELTA1"),
      new BrxDelta("DELTA2")
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("BrxTableListComponent init");
    console.log( this.brxDeltas );
  }

}
```

**Child Pane Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { BrxDelta } from '../model/BrxDelta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-brx-delta',
  template: `<kendo-splitter-pane size="100px">
                <div class="pane-content">
                  <h3>{{brxDelta.deltaName}}</h3>
                </div>
              </kendo-splitter-pane>
              `,
  styleUrls: ['brx-delta.component.scss']
})
export class BrxDeltaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('brxDelta') brxDelta:BrxDelta;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log( this.brxDelta );
  }

}
```

LATEST UPDATE...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrxDelta } from '../model/BrxDelta';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-deltas',
  // templateUrl: 'all-deltas.component.html',
  template:`<kendo-splitter orientation="horizontal" style="height: 340px;">

              <ng-template ngFor let-brxDelta [ngForOf]="brxDeltas" let-i="index">

                <kendo-splitter-pane [collapsible]="true" [resizable]="true">
                  <h3>{{brxDelta.deltaName}}</h3>
                  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="deltaPane; context:brxDelta"></ng-container>
                </kendo-splitter-pane>

              </ng-template>

            </kendo-splitter>

            <ng-template #deltaPane>

                <div class="pane-content">
                  <h3>{{deltaName}}</h3>
                </div>

            </ng-template>`
  styleUrls: ['all-deltas.component.scss']
})
export class AllDeltasComponent implements OnInit {

  brxDeltas: BrxDelta[];

  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.brxDeltas = [
      new BrxDelta("DELTA1"),
      new BrxDelta("DELTA2"),
      new BrxDelta("DELTA3")
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("BrxTableListComponent init");
    console.log( this.brxDeltas );
  }


  ngAfterViewChecked()
  {
    console.log( "! Detect changes !" );
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have ye ever read the alchemist? Ye know the bit at the end where he comes right back to where he started and found what he was looking for? Yeah this isn't like that. Only after trudging through tonnes of examples going back and forth to the docs was I able to finally stumble across the answer. Taught me a fair bit though.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrxDelta } from '../model/BrxDelta';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-deltas',
  // templateUrl: 'all-deltas.component.html',
  template:`<kendo-splitter orientation="horizontal" style="height: 340px;">

                <kendo-splitter-pane [collapsible]="true" [resizable]="true"
                        *ngFor="let brxDelta of brxDeltas; let i=index; trackBy: trackById">
                <div class="pane-content">
                  <h3>{{brxDelta.deltaName}}</h3>
                </div>
                </kendo-splitter-pane>

            </kendo-splitter>`,
  styleUrls: ['all-deltas.component.scss']
})
export class AllDeltasComponent implements OnInit {

  brxDeltas: BrxDelta[];

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.brxDeltas = [
      new BrxDelta("DELTA1"),
      new BrxDelta("DELTA2"),
      new BrxDelta("DELTA3")
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("BrxTableListComponent init");
    console.log( this.brxDeltas );
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked()
  {
    console.log( "! Detect changes !" );
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```